# mysql dynamic ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    ss.length
FROM
    result r,
    soptions ss,
    sections s
WHERE 
    r.model = s.id AND
    s.catalog2_id = ss.catalog2_id AND
    r.user_id = 1 AND
    ss.erk_id = 4 AND
    r.status_id NOT IN(1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY
    IF(r.side_id = 2, r.side_id, NULL) DESC, r.id
```

This sql command works good for me. 
I do not see the reason to describe my tables structure, because I just want to add an extra line to `ORDER BY`.
Shortly, is there any way using multiple IF conditions like below? Or I need to set `CASE WHEN ELSE`? I have tried using `CASE WHEN`, but did not get a result.

```
...
ORDER BY
  IF(r.side_id = 2, r.side_id, NULL) DESC, r.id
  IF(r.status_id = 6, r.id, NULL) DESC, r.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like this:

```
(
    CASE 
        WHEN r.side_id = 2 
        THEN r.side_id
        WHEN r.status_id = 6
        THEN r.id
        ELSE NULL
    END
) DESC,
r.id
```